# Function of : in ajax data :(

Tags: php, json, ajax

We wonder what the colon, :, in data does. We understand that the data is posted to list.php but not exactly how.

```
function paint(val){
        $(".loading").css("display","block");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "paint.php",
            data:{
                target:val,
                PaintedObjects:PaintedObjects, 
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data){
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [:] sign - used in object literal

{propertyName: "propertyValue"}

The left side of the : is the object property

The right side of the : is the properties value

in your case 
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "paint.php",

"type" is object property and "POST" is  properties value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It separates the key name from the value, the same function it operates in the rest of the code you posted (url: etc)

Read more about JSON [here](http://json.org/)

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). **Each name is followed by : (colon)** and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).

Answer (score 0):

The colon separates the key value pairs, like JSON.  It doesn't do anything different in 'data' than 'type', 'url', 'dataType', etc.  But, the data property can except different data types or structures, unlike some of the other ajax properties.

Answer (score 0):

`data` accepts `PlainObject`, `String` and `Array` formats. You can have more details at here http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject